# Efficient Algorithm for Detecting Text Duplicates in Big Dataset

Tags: algorithm, text, machine-learning, cluster-analysis

I'm working on detecting duplicates in a list of around 5 million addresses, and was wondering if there was consensus on an efficient algorithm for such a purpose. I've looked at the Dedupe library on Gitbub (https://github.com/datamade/dedupe), but based on the documentation I'm not clear that this would scale to a large application well.

As an aside, I'm just looking to define duplicates based on textual similarity - have already done a lot of cleaning on the addresses. I've been using a crude method using Levenshtein distance, but was wondering if there's anything more efficient for large datasets.

Thanks,

Comment: If sorting isn't out of the question, just lexicographically quick sort your data. Removing duplicates then becomes trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dedupe should work fine for data of that size.

There has been some excellent work by [Michael Wick](https://people.cs.umass.edu/~mwick/MikeWeb/Publications_files/wick12hierarchical.pdf) and [Beka Steorts](http://arxiv.org/abs/1312.4645) that have better complexity than dedupe.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful links!